# How to install Realtek 8723BE wifi driver?

Tags: wifi, networking

Just installed Elementary OS on an HP Stream notebook and the wifi will not connect. It detects the network, asks for a password sometimes, but never connects. Had the same problem in Lubuntu. I think it's the wifi chipset: RealTek 8723BE. Any advice?

Comment: All the above settings works for me, but have to do all those steps again after every reboot.
And no conf file is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You are right the problem probably is your wifi chipset.
Try this and see if it work.

Open the file `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` with root permission and add this: `options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N`. Save the change and restart your computer.

Comment: Call me daft, but I am unable to save changes to that file. New to EOS.

Comment: Try to open with sudo or gksudo command. Use your text editor like scratch or install gedit and open the terminal and give this command: sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf and modify the file. Now you can save.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install anything as this is an issue with HP using one antenna wire on a wireless chip with 2 antenna connections.

First we will unload the module and reload it using the module parameter to try one option for the antenna

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

Then we can check to see if any AP's are found with

```
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
```

Then we can try the other antenna option and compare results

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|quality'
```

If the `ant_sel=1` had better results then

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723beant.conf
```

If `ant_sel=2` was the better option

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723beant.conf
```

Comment: This...actually freaking worked! After a reboot, it's golden. THANK YOU!